# ReactJS html-docx-js/blob: generated docx file cannot be read by ms office and images not saved

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, blob, docx

I want to save html string as a docx file.
I tried two libraries: Blob and html-docx-js

1. With Blob, I cannot open the generated file with MS Office but I can open it with LibreOffice. Images are inserted as expected. I suspect I am doing something wrong on this line

- `var converted = new Blob(['\ufeff', htmlString], {type: 'application/msword' })`

2. With hmtl-docx-js, I am facing 2 problems:

- The generated docx file cannot be opened with LibreOffice but can be opened with MS Office.PS: LibreOffice can open normal docx files. So there is definitely a problem with the generated file.
- htmlDocx is not inserting images. I read the [documentation](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js/blob/master/test/sample.html), but I really don't know how to handle it. The `querySelectorAll('img')` cannot obviously be called on string variables.

Here is my code

```
import htmlDocx from 'html-docx-js/dist/html-docx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'
var Blob = require('blob');
...

  async saveFile(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var htmlString = this.state.html;
    var preHtml = `<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
                                    <title>Export HTML To Doc</title><style> body,html
                                      {margin-top: 0px !important;
                                        padding-top: 0px !important;
                                        padding-left: 0px !important;
                                        margin-left: 0px !important;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                        margin-left: 0px !important;
                                      }.
                                      scheduledtxt{font-size: 14.5px;} table{margin: auto 0px !important;}</head><body>`;
                                      
   htmlString = preHtml + htmlString +`</body></html>`;
   var converted = new Blob(['\ufeff', htmlString], {type: 'application/msword' })
   // var converted = htmlDocx.asBlob(htmlString)
    saveAs(converted, 'test.docx');
  }
...
```